# Android Studio:App stops working when google maps is opened from it

Tags: android

I am trying to create an app on Android Studio which will open google maps by clicking a button with the specified longitude and latitude.It works fine on Android emulator but when I try it on my mobile the app stops working after a click on the button which should open google maps. Here is the snippet of the code which is inside the onClick() function of the program.

```
        Uri uri=Uri.parse("geo:19.1500810,72.88.4537281");
        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
        intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");

        startActivity(intent);
```

Google maps should open and show the pin location of the latitude and longitude specified above but when I click the button the app stops working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This, And Update Location detail

```html
private void openlocation() {

        String addressstring = "CA";

        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
        builder.scheme("geo");
        builder.path("0,0");
        builder.query(addressstring);

        Uri Adduri = builder.build();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Adduri);

        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null){

            startActivity(intent);
        }



    }
```

Do Let Me Know After Trying This

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this method:

```
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", latitude, longitude);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Let me know if it works!

Answer (score -2):

it's better not to specify package name,i use the following code for opening map

```
        String longitude = "";
        String latitude = "";
        String label = "";
        String uriBegin = "geo:" + latitude + "," + longitude;
        String query = latitude + "," + longitude + "(" + label + ")";
        String encodedQuery = Uri.encode(query);
        String uriString = uriBegin + "?q=" + encodedQuery + "&z=16";
        Log.e(TAG, uriString);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
        Intent mapIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(mapIntent);
```